# How to Bootstrap Multiple Nodes in chef using ruby or shell script

Tags: chef-infra

In my environment I had more than 100's of systems. I want to Bootstrap Multiple Nodes in chef using ruby or shell script

```
File.readlines('hosts').each do |line|
<pre><strong>
knife bootstrap line -x ec2-user -i ~/Downloads/ram123456.pem -N node-#{line} -r 'recipe[day2]' --sudo

end</strong></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure that works. You might want some more robust error handling or whatnot but that's up to you. `knife bootstrap` is a relatively simplistic tool, if you need very high scale or other special stuffs you might want to look at other projects like Cobbler or Razor for handling system bootstraps, or check out Fog's machine bootstrap API.

Comment: No, you would have to write the for loop in Bash yourself.

Comment: shell script, if possible give outline for that how to pass hostnames and node names

Comment: Are you just asking how to write a loop in bash?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
file="hosts"
OLDIFS=$IFS
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
do
      knife bootstrap $f1 -x $f2 -P $f3 -N $f4 -r 'recipe[$f5]' --sudo
done <"$file"